# R shiny modules, reactive expression returned from server is unknown

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my "master app" i want to handle the reactives that are **returned** by included shiny modules. My problem is that I don't find a way to "catch" the returned reactive.

There is an error message when i try to resolve the reactive:  ***Warning: Error in returned_data: could not find function "returned_data"***

Is there any way to do this?

```R
require(shiny)

example_UI <- function(p_id) {
  actionButton(NS(p_id,"mergelist"), "mergelist")
}

example_Server <- function(p_id, p_list) {
  moduleServer(p_id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$mergelist, {
      return(reactive({
        rbind(data.frame("ID" = c(3, 5), "NAME" = c("lorem", "ipsum")), p_list())
      }))
    })
  })
}

example_App <- function() {
  global_list <- reactiveVal({ data.frame(ID = integer(), NAME = character()) })

  ui <- fluidPage(
    example_UI(p_id = "example"),
    verbatimTextOutput("rows")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    returned_data <- example_Server(p_id = "example", p_list = global_list)
    output$rows <- renderText({
      nrow(returned_data())
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

runApp(example_App())
```

Comment: Because the return statement in your module server is wrapped in an `observeEvent`, the server itself returns `NULL`. That’s your problem.

Comment: @Limey thank you very much. Fast and precise answer 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Limey I found my mistake and was able to solve the problem.

```
  moduleServer(p_id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    retval <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent(input$mergelist, {
      retval(...)
    })
    
    retval

  })
```